# How to add several vertical lines to ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r

```
  df <- tibble(word = c("apple", "apple","banana", "pear","pear","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),     i = seq_along(word),year=c(2000,2001,2000,2000,2001,2000,2001,2002,2000,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006))
```

I can plot it like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(year, i)) +    geom_line() +    facet_wrap(~ word)
```

I want to add vertical lines:

```
 library(strucchange)
 gft=df%>%filter(word=="A")
 ds <- ts(gft$i, start = 2000, frequency = 1)
 jj=breakdates(breakpoints(ds ~ 1,2))
```

I did this for "A",How to do this for all other words? And add jj i.e. `2001 2003 2006`  to the plot above as vertical lines.

Comment: Just add `geom_vline(xintercept = jj)` beefore `facet_wrap`.

Comment: thanks much. but this add jj for all facets. I need to add jj to its facet.

Comment: this jj is for the word A but it is added for all words.

Comment: Try with `geom_vline(data = data.frame(xintercept = jj, word = "A"), aes(xintercept = xintercept))` which contains the faceting var and so will only add vlines to panel "A".

Comment: @stefan   thanks  but the idea is to do this for all words and facet not  only A (each word associated to its jj)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, just prepare your data for the desired vertical lines.

```
vlines <- tibble(word = c("apple", "banana", "pear", "A"), lines = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2004))

ggplot(df, aes(year, i)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ word) +
  geom_vline(data = vlines, aes(xintercept = lines, group = word))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the breakpoint lines only to the facet of `word == "A"`, create a new data.frame with those break points and a column `word`. Then use that data.frame in `geom_vline`.

```
gftjj <- data.frame(word = unique(gft$word), jj)

ggplot(df, aes(year, i)) +
  geom_line() +    
  geom_vline(data = gftjj, aes(xintercept = jj)) +
  facet_wrap(~ word)
```

[image]